# SAS Dollar Format Losing zero cents

Tags: sas

My employer recently switched from base SAS to SAS Enterprise Guide version 7.12. I have code that I ran in the past with no problem, but now the same code is having trouble formatting dollar amounts with zero cents. I am using the format dollar20.2. If the data that I am working with has zero cents, it places the decimal in the wrong location.

For example, 117650 becomes $1,176.50 instead of $117,650.00

Comment: Looks like somehow an informat of 20.2 is being applied - the .2 tells SAS there must be 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing INFORMAT and FORMAT.  The INFORMAT tells SAS how to convert text strings into values and the FORMAT tells SAS how to convert values into text strings.  If you have a number and use the `DOLLAR20.2` format it will display the data with two decimal places.  But if you read data with the `DOLLAR20.2` informat then you are telling SAS that when that text string does not have a decimal place then assume one is implied before the last two digits. Basically it divided the value by 100.  In general it is a bad idea to specify decimal positions on your INFORMATS, unless you are positive that you want SAS to supply the decimal point when one is not present.

You probably want to use `DOLLAR20.` (or the equivalent `COMMA20.`) as your INFORMAT.